# How to access JSON payload

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a bit of a problem trying to use the json that i load with angular-translate. I Mean, how can i access it? The file loads and all is good other than that i don't know how to set it.

I want to to something like:

```
$scope.translations = /* what i get back as json */
```

Here is my code for loading the file.

```
angular.module('app.core').config(config);

/* @ngInject */
function config($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/assets/lang/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fi');
}
```

Comment: Solved it myself. It was just a matter of binding it to its element in the view.

Comment: Like: {{ "site.navigation.item1" | translate }}